# How to test REST API google maps?

Tags: rest, api, maps, soapui, gets

I want to test the google maps API so I can see the resources that the API have, i found the SoapUI REadyAPI, but I'm still confused.
Is there a way to make this REST API calls (gets) from console so i can see the JSON of Google maps?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried `curl` command line utility?

Comment: No i haven't, to be honest i don't even know what is that... Does it allow to make the gets calls from the API?

Comment: Since you've asked regarding sending these requests from console, this is the best available option. `CURL` utility comes with most linux OS, if it is not available to you then you can install it using (`yum install curl` on centos or `apt-get install curl` on ubuntu/debian. Also, if you are using windows then fear not, you can install git for windows and use git bash terminal which has many linux command line tools)e.g. `curl -k -L -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"your_payload_key": "your_payload_value", ...}' -X POST https://your.url.extn/request/path`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chrome has an extension called rest client where you could test from and see the JSON response. You can also use postman to test. https://www.getpostman.com/ . Both will work very easily with google maps api.

Comment: Ok, so i install both to try, but how do i enter the URL so the JSON data can be displayed. I still have problems figuring out how to display the resource info from maps... Can you help me with that?

Comment: so enter the web API request url in the url textbox. next specify that the HTTP method is a GET then run it. you should return a json in the response body. If you return an error, follow the error and make adjustments until you get a 200 response

Comment: Oh ok, i understand now, i read the documentation and with your help everything is clearer. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start?hl=es-419  thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend creating a Collection in Postman called "Google APIs".

Within that collection, add a GET request called "Get Geocode JSON".

Add `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json` to the request url input.

Add three key-value pairs in the Params tab:

| KEY | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| address | 802/8 Brown Street, Chatswood 2067 |
| components | country:AU |
| key | {{key}} |

Of course, your `address` and `components` values will differ.  I am using a variable `{{key}}` which I have defined within the Google APIs collection.

[image]

Finally, click the Send button and view the results in body of the results.

Postman also offers many automatically generated coding implementations for a variety of languages.  Click the `</>` symbol on the right side of the application and select your preferred programming language.